# compress chunks of data using zlib python

Tags: python, zlib

I have a file, which I need to read into memory chunk by chunk and compress it.

For this I am using Zlib library. This library provides streaming option by using method `compressobj()`.

```
def read_in_chunks(file_object, chunk_size=1024*2):
    while True:
    data = file_object.read(chunk_size)
    if not data:
        break
    yield data

def compress_chunks(gen_obj):
    for i in gen_obj: 
        compress = zlib.compressobj(2, zlib.DEFLATED, -15)
        compressed_data = compress.compress(i)+compress.flush()
        yield (compressed_data)

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    test_data = open('test.txt','rb')
    chunk_input  = read_in_chunks(test_data)
    compressed_data  = compress_chunks(chunk_input)
    with open('test_zip_file.dat','wb') as ff:
        for d in compressed_data:
            ff.write(d)
    f.close()
```

Using this above code I am able to write the file back into file in compressed manner.

But to read it back I am able to follow the same procedure.

I need to read back chunks of data into memory decompress it and write back to file.

I am facing below issues while decompressing object in chunks

1) `zlib: Error -3 while decompressing data: invalid distance too far back`:

This happens when I try to create new decompress object for every chunk with adding `zlib.decompress.flush()`

2) `Loss of data`:

When I don't create new object for each chunk and try to decompress it for many chunks I get a blank string and get less data than the original file.

```
def read_in_chunks(file_object, chunk_size=1024*2):
    while True:
    data = file_object.read(chunk_size)
    if not data:
        break
    yield data   
def decompress_chunks(gen_obj):
    decom = zlib.decompressobj(-15)
    for i in gen_obj:
        decom_data = decom.decompress(i)
        yield(decom_data)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    zip_Data = open('test_zip_file.dat','rb')
    zip_data_c = read_in_chunks(zip_Data)
    dz = decompress_chunks(zip_data_c)
    with open('test4.txt','wb') as tf:
        for i in dz:
            tf.write(i)
```

Comment: **sort of one issue is after compressing chunks and writing to file, I am not reading the exact compressed string to decompress**

Answer (score 1):

When writing compressed chunk to file, there wasn't any delimiter. So, while reading it back for decompression, program wasn't able to decompress the compressed string.

By adding a delimiter I am able to decompress the data and able to retrieve the actual data.